# Install Snow Leopard on Toshiba x86 machine?

Tags: macos, mac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to install Mac OS X on customized hardware?](https://superuser.com/questions/24624/is-it-possible-to-install-mac-os-x-on-customized-hardware)

Well, I don't think its possible - but I'm curious why not - but can someone install Mac OS's on Intel machines?  For along time the architecture was different RISC vs x86, but then later they moved to x86, so how difficult is it to install Snow Leopard on a regular Wintel laptop / desktop?

Comment: Voted to close: exact duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/24624/is-it-possible-to-install-mac-os-x-on-customized-hardware and http://superuser.com/questions/10174/osx86-on-thinkpad-x41 on top of it not being technically legal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a look around [this website](http://lifehacker.com/5351485/how-to-build-a-hackintosh-with-snow-leopard-start-to-finish) and see if u like the guide.